How do I escape this properly in bash?
C_CYAN='\033[36m'
echo -e "\\${C_CYAN}hello";

Expected:
\hello in with the word hello in cyan
Actual:
\033[36mhello

Use C_CYAN=$(tput setf 3) instead of hard-coding terminal-specific escape codes.

Are you asking how to print a \ in front of ${C_CYAN} or something else?

You can use printf:
printf '\%bhello\n' "$C_CYAN"

but as @chepner says in his comment it's better to use tput than hardcoding escape sequences:
C_CYAN=$(tput setf 3)


This is great! This cleans up my everything completely!

Use tput as others have suggested but also reset the color after using it, e.g.:
$ c_cyan=$(tput setf 3)
$ c_reset=$(tput sgr0)
$ printf "\\${c_cyan}hello${c_reset}\n"
\hello
$ printf "I said ${c_cyan}hello${c_reset} to them\n"
I said hello to them


Also, don't use all upper case names for non-exported variables, see Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization.

You need to store the actual ANSI code in $C_CYAN, not its escaped version:
C_CYAN=$'\033[36m'
       ~

Or, if you can't change $C_CYAN:
eval echo -e "\\\\\\\\\\${C_CYAN}hello"

But I'd strongly advocate for the former.
